# How nested dependencies are bundled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module

Let's suppose that my app consists of:

app.js

```
const k = require("K");
const c = require("C");
```

Package `K` has following dependencies:

```
const ka = require("A");
const kb = require("B");
const kc = require("C");
```

Does it means that after bundling process the source from package "C" will be doubled in output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Bundlers and Node.js module-handling APIs *cache* each module.  Each module is read and interpreted only one time. Subsequent `require` calls return/refer to a cached module.

Comment: I found confirmation of your information in Node.js documentation https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_caching